# Change what phantomjs posts to a form

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to get phantomjs to change what it posts to a form, I tried changing the request data like so:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  if(requestData.url.match(/some_form\.php/)){
    requestData.postData = 'str=updated_content';
  }
};
```

But the original data gets posted for some reason. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Docs don't say anything about postData property  http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html  Where did you find that?

Comment: Just by inspecting requestData

Comment: I guess `networkRequest.changeUrl(url)` can be used to pass that specific request through a proxy of some sort and change the contents. Remember that PhantomJS also has a webserver module, which might be used to implement such a minimal proxy in the same script. This might be a lot of code and possibly not worth the trouble.

Comment: @artjomB it sounds like you're saying it can't be done. I guess I'll leave this one open and in the future maybe that will change which would be interesting.

Comment: It cannot be done easily, but I'm sure it can be done.